# Postgresql 15 : SELECT count(*) hangs indefinitely when run from a spring app

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

When I run a complex SELECT count(*) query on a postgresql DB [PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit] from my Java 17 spring boot mybatis application, the query hangs, and never returns.

If I run the same query against the same DB, but using DBeaver functionality, the query returns in ~ 300 milliseconds. So it doesn't seem to be something wrong with the DB, but still the query sent from the java app seems to be hanging at the DB level.

My app is a Java 17, spring boot postgresql application with the following versions:

```
<springboot.version>3.0.4</springboot.version>
        <hikariCP.version>5.0.1</hikariCP.version>
        <postgresql.driver.version>42.5.4</postgresql.driver.version>
        <mybatis.version>3.5.13</mybatis.version>
        <mybatis.spring.version>3.0.1</mybatis.spring.version>
        <mybatis.spring.boot.starter.version>3.0.1</mybatis.spring.boot.starter.version>
```

The logs that my app is generating when sending this query are:

```
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.416Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServletrlf(GET "/search?lm=10&s=tt&o=0&lc=en&la=45.4906639&lg=-73.4654282&dk=5&a=4", parameters={masked}) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.417Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMappingrlf(Mapped to com.test.mw.controllers.SearchController#search(String, Integer, Integer, List, String, Double, Double, Double, List, List, List, List, List, List, List, Integer, List, Integer, Integer, UserDBO)) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.420Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager] org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManagerrlf(Creating new transaction with name [com.test.mw.services.SearchService.search]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.421Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager] org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManagerrlf(Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@587237285 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@5189b047] for JDBC transaction) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.421Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager] org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManagerrlf(Switching JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@587237285 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@5189b047] to manual commit) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.423Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtilsrlf(Creating a new SqlSession) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.423Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtilsrlf(Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@2dc76db5]) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.425Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransactionrlf(JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@587237285 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@5189b047] will be managed by Spring) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.425Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [com.test.mw.db.mappers.SearchMapper.getSearchProductsCount] com.test.mw.db.mappers.SearchMapper.getSearchProductsCountrlf(==>  Preparing: SELECT count(*) FROM products p LEFT JOIN products_locations pl ON pl.product_id = p.id AND (pl.latitude <= ? OR pl.latitude IS NULL) AND (pl.latitude >= ? OR pl.latitude IS NULL) AND (pl.longitude <= ? OR pl.longitude IS NULL) AND (pl.longitude >= ? OR pl.longitude IS NULL) LEFT JOIN products_descriptions pd ON pd.product_id = p.id AND pd.locale = ? WHERE 1 = 1 AND p.id IN ( (SELECT id FROM products WHERE universal_product_code ILIKE ? OR model ILIKE ? OR isbn ILIKE ?) UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_descriptions WHERE (title ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ? OR ts_title @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?) OR ts_description @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?)) AND locale = ? ) UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_contents WHERE content_id IN (SELECT id FROM contents WHERE (value ILIKE ? OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?)) AND locale = ? )) UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_tags WHERE tag_id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE (value ILIKE ? OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?)) AND locale = ? )) UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_labels WHERE label_id IN (SELECT id FROM labels WHERE (value ILIKE ? OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?)) AND locale = ? )) UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_brands WHERE brand_id IN (SELECT id FROM brands WHERE (value ILIKE ? OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?)) AND locale = ? )) UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_nutrition_facts WHERE id IN (SELECT product_nutrition_fact_id FROM products_nutrition_facts_names WHERE nutrient_name_id IN (SELECT id FROM nutrients_names WHERE (value ILIKE ? OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(?::regconfig, ?)) AND locale = ? ))) )) 
middleware_1  | 2023-03-13T16:55:50.430Z <> {thread=http-nio-8080-exec-2} DEBUG: [com.test.mw.db.mappers.SearchMapper.getSearchProductsCount] com.test.mw.db.mappers.SearchMapper.getSearchProductsCountrlf(==> Parameters: 45.53563(Double), 45.4457(Double), -73.40128(Double), -73.52957(Double), en(String), %tt%(String), %tt%(String), %tt%(String), %tt%(String), %tt%(String), english(String), tt(String), english(String), tt(String), en(String), %tt%(String), english(String), tt(String), en(String), %tt%(String), english(String), tt(String), en(String), %tt%(String), english(String), tt(String), en(String), %tt%(String), english(String), tt(String), en(String), %tt%(String), english(String), tt(String), en(String))
```

The transaction status on postgresql side looks like this:

```
16384   mw  68  39  10  user    PostgreSQL JDBC Driver              2023-03-13 12:55:50.684 -0400       2023-03-13 12:55:50.470 -0400   2023-03-13 12:55:50.701 -0400           active              "SELECT count(*)
        FROM products p
        LEFT JOIN products_locations pl ON pl.product_id = p.id  AND (pl.latitude <= $1 OR pl.latitude IS NULL)  
          AND (pl.latitude >= $2 OR pl.latitude IS NULL) 
          AND (pl.longitude <= $3 OR pl.longitude IS NULL)  
          AND (pl.longitude >= $4 OR pl.longitude IS NULL) 
        LEFT JOIN products_descriptions pd ON pd.product_id = p.id  AND pd.locale = $5 
        WHERE 1 = 1
                AND p.id IN (
                    (SELECT id FROM products WHERE universal_product_code ILIKE $6 OR model ILIKE $7 OR isbn ILIKE $8) UNION
                    (SELECT product_id FROM products_descriptions WHERE (title ILIKE $9 OR description ILIKE $10 OR ts_title @@ websearch_to_tsquery($11::regconfig, $12) OR ts_description @@ websearch_to_tsquery($13::regconfig, $14))  AND locale = $15 ) UNION
                    (SELECT product_id FROM products_conte" parallel worker
```

My postgresql docker definition looks like this:

```
FROM groonga/pgroonga:latest-alpine-15-slim

# install wget curl iconv
RUN apk add --no-cache wget curl

# install polish full text search
RUN wget https://sjp.pl/sl/ort/sjp-ispell-pl-20230301-src.tar.bz2
RUN tar xvjf sjp-ispell-pl-20230301-src.tar.bz2
RUN cd sjp-ispell-pl-20230301 \
    iconv -f ISO_8859-2 -t utf-8 polish.aff > polish.affix \
    iconv -f ISO_8859-2 -t utf-8 polish.all > polish.dict
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominem/stopwords/master/polish.stopwords.txt > polish.stop
RUN cp polish.affix `pg_config --sharedir`/tsearch_data/
RUN cp polish.dict `pg_config --sharedir`/tsearch_data/
RUN cp polish.stop `pg_config --sharedir`/tsearch_data/
```

I just added polish full text support on top of pgroonga container.

I have about 25k unique products entries in my products DB

The only difference that I'm seeing when running the query on spring app Vs running the same query from DBeaver, is the backed_type:
For Dbeaver is set to "client backend" while for sring app is set to : "parallel worker"

Any idea what might be causing this hanging behavior ?

Thanks

Spring DS configs:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://mw-db:5432/mw
    username: *****
    password: *****
    idle-timeout: 60000
    minimum-idle: 20
    connection-timeout: 60000
    pool-name: AppPool
    initialization-fail-timeout: 30000
    login-timeout: 30000
```

Parametrized query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN products_locations pl ON pl.product_id = p.id AND (pl.latitude <= 45.53563 OR pl.latitude IS NULL) AND (pl.latitude >= 45.4457 OR pl.latitude IS NULL) AND (pl.longitude <= -73.40128 OR pl.longitude IS NULL) AND (pl.longitude >= -73.52957 OR pl.longitude IS NULL) 
LEFT JOIN products_descriptions pd ON pd.product_id = p.id AND pd.locale = 'en' 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND p.id IN ( 
(SELECT id FROM products WHERE universal_product_code ILIKE '%tt%' OR model ILIKE '%tt%' OR isbn ILIKE '%tt%') 
UNION 
(SELECT product_id FROM products_descriptions WHERE (title ILIKE '%tt%' OR description ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_title @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%') OR ts_description @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' ) 
UNION 
(SELECT product_id FROM products_contents WHERE content_id IN (SELECT id FROM contents WHERE (value ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' ))
 UNION 
 (SELECT product_id FROM products_tags WHERE tag_id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE (value ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' ))
 UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_labels WHERE label_id IN (SELECT id FROM labels WHERE (value ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' ))
 UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_brands WHERE brand_id IN (SELECT id FROM brands WHERE (value ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' )) 
 UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_nutrition_facts WHERE id IN (SELECT product_nutrition_fact_id FROM products_nutrition_facts_names WHERE nutrient_name_id IN (SELECT id FROM nutrients_names WHERE (value ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' ))) )
```

Contents table problematic entries at the top:

```
INSERT INTO public.contents (id,value,locale,username,creation_time,update_time,"language",ts_value) VALUES
     ('d26c5793-cdf3-4c63-bb82-b1a30b15e62d','or','en','test','2023-03-12 22:58:58.740','2023-03-12 22:58:58.740','english',''),
     ('aceb6396-4b19-4b6b-94a2-29908d21b888','● ● ● ●','en','test','2023-03-12 22:27:00.740','2023-03-12 22:27:00.740','english',''),
     ('4bdf1d2c-fff4-4c8f-b4c8-13ac462d23ce','do','en','test','2023-03-12 22:28:24.448','2023-03-12 22:28:24.448','english',''),
     ('e479fce9-2ff0-4e2b-9e09-fcaac326868b','ma','fr','test','2023-03-12 19:44:57.436','2023-03-12 19:44:57.436','french',''),
     ('41cd22b7-2413-43f8-aa02-fa3fc7bd49ad','i','en','test','2023-03-12 22:52:43.952','2023-03-12 22:52:43.952','english',''),
     ('f9b92dd9-8c93-40c6-817c-a8f8befe378d','so','en','test','2023-03-12 22:58:48.571','2023-03-12 22:58:48.571','english',''),
     ('338ce908-45a9-468c-8fc8-99efb0fbd928','s','fr','test','2023-03-12 22:30:35.650','2023-03-12 22:30:35.650','french',''),
     ('10fe6332-d2ce-411f-97d9-8c96e4e63f7b','eu','fr','test','2023-03-12 15:47:07.653','2023-03-12 15:47:07.653','french',''),
     ('27c65c40-db3d-4c1d-975a-f975e608a060','pour','fr','test','2023-03-12 19:49:27.237','2023-03-12 19:49:27.237','french',''),
     ('dc5f5218-7026-4199-8faa-60bd71080d19','ait','fr','test','2023-03-12 19:44:57.017','2023-03-12 19:44:57.017','french','');
INSERT INTO public.contents (id,value,locale,username,creation_time,update_time,"language",ts_value) VALUES
     ('0b686e39-186d-41a9-b8d4-745cf6cd18b9','par','fr','test','2023-03-12 20:05:22.196','2023-03-12 20:05:22.196','french',''),
     ('c146357c-6029-46c9-9d1a-77da7d0709b8','s','en','test','2023-03-12 19:41:26.680','2023-03-12 19:41:26.680','english',''),
     ('397d3b9e-f8f0-4904-8956-be99b7409830','t','en','test','2023-03-12 15:47:53.752','2023-03-12 15:47:53.752','english',''),
     ('fc69975c-146d-4523-b12c-4bbf9bfaa725','0','en','test','2023-03-12 23:08:37.103','2023-03-12 23:08:37.103','english','''0'':1'),
     ('7bea93f0-0b50-46aa-b09e-1d62ab1ac07f','1','ru','test','2023-03-12 22:46:26.893','2023-03-12 22:46:26.893','russian','''1'':1'),
     ('3b041103-ef2f-4c83-aca1-197c596be42d','1','fr','test','2023-03-12 19:42:12.103','2023-03-12 19:42:12.103','french','''1'':1'),
     ('cf69b063-bea0-4e93-b279-1e300d116f5e','12','fr','test','2023-03-12 19:40:51.103','2023-03-12 19:40:51.103','french','''12'':1'),
     ('d2d0c626-2c05-4170-af1e-b6877a2f4188','14','en','test','2023-03-12 23:01:08.234','2023-03-12 23:01:08.234','english','''14'':1'),
     ('b1baf664-d46f-439a-8d67-735eb5fbe0a4','20','en','test','2023-03-12 22:37:19.969','2023-03-12 22:37:19.969','english','''20'':1'),
     ('a90c6a74-97ee-4b07-adba-eaa26f5bd98f','23','en','test','2023-03-12 22:55:24.206','2023-03-12 22:55:24.206','english','''23'':1');
```

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.contents (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    value varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    locale varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    creation_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    update_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    "language" regconfig NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple'::regconfig,
    ts_value tsvector NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector(language, value::text)) STORED,
    CONSTRAINT contents_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT contents_value_locale_key UNIQUE (value,locale)
);
CREATE INDEX c_ts_value_idx ON public.contents (ts_value);
CREATE INDEX c_value_idx ON public.contents (value);
CREATE INDEX contents_id_idx ON public.contents (id);
CREATE INDEX contents_locale_idx ON public.contents (locale);
```

Comment: In your logs I see Spring creates new transaction. Any chance you make this call from some request handler, which makes transactional change to one of the rows to be returned, and makes read call using new TX before committing running TX?

Comment: I don't have any other DB operation going on before this select count(*) in that method / controller. Also when I'm running this query, there are no other requests hitting the system. And yes the method is annotated with  aTransactional so a new transaction is started (but this is for logic, following this problematic query) The query behaves the same even if I remove the   aTransactional annotation.

Comment: Ok. I do not know what's going on here but it looks like deadlock. I would reduce query to `select 1`, if it works then `select (*) from product` and so to find at what point it breaks so it could give you more clues.

Comment: Yeah I was actually doing that. It seems the deadlock starts to behave once I add this into the query:  UNION (SELECT product_id FROM products_contents WHERE content_id IN (SELECT id FROM contents WHERE (value ILIKE '%tt%' OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english'::regconfig, '%tt%')) AND locale = 'en' ))    . But still this does not explain why the same query works from DBeaver but not from Spring app

Comment: Did you check pg_stat_activity? Could you share the results?

Comment: can you test your query with static values everywhere where text search is used? E.g. `websearch_to_tsquery` etc Probably, from DBBeaver you use static values and it is why it works fast?

Comment: Note that alpine isn't really suitable for a production setup of a database server due to it's much slower memory allocation.

Comment: @FrankHeikens the pg_stat_activity is in the description above. AlexanderPavlov that's a good idea. I will try it if what I'm working on now won't work. Currently I am trying to extract that UNIONs collection into some separate queries and build that IDs list in the Java code. a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the time. This env is a dev environment not a prod one, so I should be ok with the alpine instance.

Comment: Some more updates, after refactoring my code, I still see the same behavior. Again blocking around products_contents query. Playing with the query I've noticed that the problem actually comes from the statement: OR ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(#{language}::regconfig, #{filter}). Digging into the DB I noticed that under the contents table where the ts_value column is located, some of the rows are missing the values in ts_value  column.  I will add the DB content into the issue description. Could that be the cause of the problem ?!?! I will try with some static values too.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov with static values it works.

Comment: I do not know how text search is implemented in PG. Could it regenerate some index on first query or smth like that?

Comment: hm, probably you need FTS indices, not columnar https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX

Comment: Your query just runs forever. I'd start with these many `UNION`ed subqueries at the end and see how long they take. Also, you should immediately replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`, because that will perform much better. Looking at your query, it seems like a "total result set count" query as described [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/#total-count), so the simplest solution may be not to run it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a working solution for my problem. Thanks everyone for your precious feedback!

So as I've mentioned earlier, the problem was coming from the `ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery(#{language}::regconfig, #{filter})`  statement when run on the contents table. It seems the empty ts_value entries are not behind this behavior. I'm still not clear why I am seeing this behavior only on this table.

Anyhow, the way I managed to make it run is to set statically the language param. That param is controlled by my logic, so I can afford that, without worrying of any potential SQL injection threats on that area.

The fix for a mybatis query will look like this :

`ts_value @@ websearch_to_tsquery('${language}'::regconfig, #{filter})`